# Otimizar pesquisa no MySql

Tags: mysql, otimização

Olá tenho uma query que não consigo otimizar.

Registros: **1.904.447** registros
Nome: tabela_mae

Relacionado a
Registros: **10.748.360** registros
Nome: tabela_filho

```
-- index criado para id_tabela_mae
-- index criado para data
SELECT tabela_mae.nome FROM tabela_mae INNER JOIN tabela_filho ON 
tabela_mae.id = tabela_filho.id_tabela_mae AND DATE(tabela_filho.data) 
BETWEEN  '2015-06-09' AND '2015-06-09' ORDER BY tabela_mae.flag_fechou,
tabela_mae.data_fechou ASC
```

Esse comando demora mais de 20 segundos para executar, se tirar o `ORDER BY`, demora 10 segundos.

Aparentemente o problema é que no `between` tem que varrer a tabela toda para encontrar poucos registros.

Answer (score 2):

Preste atenção nesse texto.

1) Você deverá configurar índices para os campos que usar no `WHERE`. O primeiro passo é fazer um planejamento e tentar encontrar os campos que estão tomando tempo e recursos do servidor.

2) Usando o phpMyAdmin, vá em Estrutura.

3) Desça um pouco a tela, e na tabela de índices, observe a cardinalidade de sua chave primária ou índice. Em nosso exemplo, temos uma tabela bastante grande, com uma chave primária de cardinalidade superior a 100 mil.

O que isso significa? Quando fizermos uma query nesta tabela, o mysql irá procurar em cada um dos 100 mil registros, um por um.

Com o índice criado corretamente, de um modo geral, a cardinalidade da chave precisa ficar entre 50 e 400. Tudo depende da sua aplicação, do volume de dados, etc.

Em nosso teste, a query demorou quase 1 minuto para ser executada (sem os índices configuradas).

4) No phpMyAdmin vá em “SQL” . Para criar o índice, digite:

```
CREATE INDEX <nome_do_indice> ON <tabela> ( <campo>(<tamanho>) )
```

no nosso exemplo:

```
CREATE INDEX nomedomeuindice ON contador ( prot(2) )
```

#### Mas o que significa de fato este 'tamanho'?

Considere que estejamos criando um índice de tamanho (5).

Caso os registros do nosso banco sejam:

**João Vitor

Paulo Fagundes

José Cruz

João Guilherme

José Silva

Paulo Roberto

João Francisco

Paulo Amorim**

Criando uma chave com 5 posições, o mysql organizará da seguinte forma:

[image: Tabela]

Quando fizermos uma query: `SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE nome = “João Vitor”` , ao invés do MySQL percorrer todos os 8 registros da nossa tabela-exemplo, ele irá verificar apenas os 3 índices que criamos.

Conforme mostrado em nosso vídeo, esta otimização dentro de uma tabela com  muitos registros, irá lhe economizar bastante tempo e processamento!

A aplicação de índices no nosso banco de dados com mais de 100 mil registros, reduziu o tempo da query de quase 1 minuto para menos de 0,01 segundos !

#### Como faço para descobrir qual campo preciso indexar?

Basta executar suas queries no phpMyAdmin, colocando “desc” antes. O mysql irá lhe mostrar passo a passo o caminho que ele está percorrendo para lhe fornecer um resultado.

**Exemplo:**

```
desc SELECT * FROM `contador` WHERE prot=’03554d6b’
```

**Resultado:**

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra 
1 SIMPLE contador ref nomedomeuindice nomedomeuindice 4 const 462 Using where
```

[Fonte](http://www.homehost.com.br/blog/como-otimizar-um-banco-mysql-usando-indices/)

Comment: +1 pelo uso do `DESCRIBE`, mas eu acho que cabe mencionar que o MySQL não usa (e não tem como ser forçado a usar índices pra consultas tipo `DATE(…) BETWEEN … AND …`, mas nesse caso particular, a consulta pode ser resscrita como `… BETWEEN '… 00:00:00' AND '… 23:59:59'`.

Comment: Verdade @ctgPi mas acredito que dá pra fazer uma adaptação.