# O que são as cardinalidades dos indexes?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, índices

Verificando os indexes através do seguinte comando:

```
show indexes from tabela_exemplo;
```

A coluna `Cardinality` me deixou com dúvidas. Ela guarda um valor inteiro para cada index apontado para uma ou mais colunas correspondente aos indexes.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é esta cardinalidade?
2. Qual é a relação que a cardinalidade tem com os indexes?

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89527/101. Também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79889/101 Útil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253927/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410408/101. Ainda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68380/101.